# golang static check whether implement interface with type parameter

Tags: go

without type parameter, we can use this to check *type* whether impl interface.

```golang
type R struct{}

func (r R) Read([]byte) (int, error)

var _ io.Reader = R{}
```

how do this *static* check with **type parameter** ?
e.g

```golang
type Comparator[T any] interface {
    // a.Compare(b) =>
    // -1 : a < b
    //  0 : a == b
    //  1 : a > b
    Compare(t T) int
    Equal(t T) bool
}

type SortArray[E Comparator[E]] interface {
    BinarySearch(e E) (int, error)
}

type MyArray[E Comparator[E]] struct{
    inner []E
}

func (*MyArray[E]) BinarySearch(e E) (int, error)
```

how check whether `*MyArray` impl `SortArray` when compile time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need to define a type which impl `Comparator[T]`.

```golang
type Comparator[T any] interface {
    // a.Compare(b) =>
    // -1 : a < b
    //  0 : a == b
    //  1 : a > b
    Compare(t T) int
    Equal(t T) bool
}

type SortArray[E Comparator[E]] interface {
    BinarySearch(e E) (int, error)
}

type MyArray[E Comparator[E]] struct{
    inner []E
}

func (*MyArray[E]) BinarySearch(e E) (int, error){
    return 0, nil
}

func _[E Comparator[E]]() SortArray[E]{
    var arr MyArray[E]
    return &arr
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate `*MyArray[X]` with a type `X` that is a `Comparator`.

```
type testComparator struct {
   Comparator[testComparator]
}

var _ SortArray[testComparator] = &MyArray[testComparator]{}
```

Comment: any other way here? defining a fake type is too verbose. (although i do use it